# Can't save type System.Version to My.Settings

Tags: vb.net, my.settings, system.version

I have a small test project for checking application version from a server and prompting a user to update. Everything works fine except that I can't save a type of `System.Version` to `My.Settings`. (I want to save the new version in case a user requests not to be reminded about it again.)

Now, I know I can save Version as a string and convert it back and forth - which I have done to get around this problem - but as `System.Version` is listed in the available setting data types, I figure it should work. But instead of saving the version, it merely saves an XML entry "Version" without a value (refer below).

I'm using VB.NET, VS 2013, .NET 4.

Here's some code to look at:

**Settings.Designer.vb**

```
<Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(),  _
Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>  _
Public Property DoNotRemindVersion() As Global.System.Version
    Get
        Return CType(Me("DoNotRemindVersion"),Global.System.Version)
    End Get
    Set
        Me("DoNotRemindVersion") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

**Example assignment**

```
If My.Settings.DoNotRemind Then My.Settings.DoNotRemindVersion = oVersion.NewVersion
```

(`oVersion.NewVersion` is of type `System.Version`.)

**As saved in user.config**

```
<setting name="DoNotRemindVersion" serializeAs="Xml">
    <value>
        <Version xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </value>
</setting>
```

So, what am I doing wrong? I've read a few posts about having to serialize classes to save them to user settings, but this is a simple Version number, which, on the face of things, I would expect to be a supported data type.

Comment: I've tried adding a setting of type `Version` and setting its value in the project properties and none of the values that I would expect to work actually do work, so I'm guessing that it's just not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [System.Version Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) is marked with the `SerializableAttribute` but you will need to mark the property with the [SettingsSerializeAsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsserializeasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass the [System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsserializeas(v=vs.110).aspx#Members) value.

You can not use the Project Settings designer interface to automatically generate the code like you have found in the `Settings.designer.vb` file.  You will need to extend the My Namespace - MySettings Class yourself.  This is one of areas that partial classes are useful.

Add a new class file to your project and name something creative like CustomMySettings.  Select and delete the auto-generated code in this new file and replace it with the following code.

```
Namespace My
    Partial Friend NotInheritable Class MySettings
        ' The trick here is to tell it serialize as binary
        <Global.System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs(System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)> _
        <Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(), _
        Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()> _
        Public Property DoNotRemindVersion() As Global.System.Version
            Get
                    Return CType(Me("DoNotRemindVersion"), Global.System.Version)
            End Get
            Set(value As Global.System.Version)
                    Me("DoNotRemindVersion") = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This will allow you to use `My.Settings.DoNotRemindVersion` just like if you created the setting via the designer.  The first time you access the setting, it will have a null (Nothing) value, so you may what to initialize it with something like the following in a Form.Load event handler.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim savedVersion As Version = My.Settings.DoNotRemindVersion
    If savedVersion Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.DoNotRemindVersion = New Version(1, 0)
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @TnTinMan Thanks for your answer. 100% from a functional POV, tho I might stick with a string conversion for simplicity, settings readability, etc. It's a shame to have to jump through these hoops for something so simple. MS should only show in Browse the data types which are natively-supported by My.Settings, I think. It's misleading otherwise.